# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TableRow.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, android-tablelayout

I am trying to use table layout with recyclerView but it is giving the error:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TableRow.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference.

There is my adapter class:

```
public class CompanyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CompanyAdapter.bookViewHolder> {

ArrayList<DataClass> arrayList;
TextView deposit;
TextView purchase;
TextView date;
TableRow tableRow;
TableLayout tableLayout;

public CompanyAdapter(ArrayList<DataClass> arrayList){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override
public bookViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    View view = 

 LayoutInflater.
from(context).inflate(R.layout.company_list_item,parent,false);
    return new bookViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(bookViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DataClass dataClass = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.bind(dataClass);
    //bookNameTV.setText(dataClass.getBook());
    //authorNameTV.setText(dataClass.getAuthor());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public class bookViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{



    public bookViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        deposit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deposit);
        purchase = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.purchase);
        date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.maintablelayout);

    }

    public void bind(DataClass dataClass){
        deposit.setText(Integer.toString(dataClass.getAmount()));
        purchase.setText(Integer.toString(dataClass.getAmount()));
        date.setText(dataClass.date);
        tableRow.addView(deposit);
        tableRow.addView(purchase);
        tableRow.addView(date);
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));// giving error

    }
}
}
```

One more question, Is there any better way to use tableLayout with recycler View without using any library?
Thanks..!

Comment: is problem solved?

Comment: Above mentioned problem was solved. But getting another error: You must call removeView() on the child's parent. I tried if(tableRow.getParent() != null){tableLayout.removeAllViews}; but getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing `tableRow` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You must create new TableRow

Use this code

```
TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(context); 
tableRow.addView(deposit);
    tableRow.addView(purchase);
    tableRow.addView(date);
    if(tableRow.getParent()!=null){
        ((ViewGroup)tableRow.getParent()).removeView(tableRow);
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: getting another error:The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. Where to add this removeView()?

Comment: try edited code @burhansabir

Answer (score 0):

`TableRow` is an instance variable, so JAVA will initialize this with null value at runtime and you can't call any method with null value. You have to assign an object to the `TableRow` reference variable.

like:

```
tableRow=new TableRow(context);
```

Comment: i have added "tableRow = new TableRow(context);" in bookViewHolder and removeAllViews() in Bind method like : date.setText(dataClass.date);
            tableRow.removeAllViews();
            tableRow.addView(deposit); But still getting error:The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: You are adding same object again and again that's why you are getting error  You must call removeView() on the child's parent , You need to change the code. In recycle view it reuse the object so you can not add same object agin in TableView. 

I am referring these objects 

tableRow.addView(deposit);
        tableRow.addView(purchase);
        tableRow.addView(date);

Comment: but in my case list item or recyclable object is tableRow not deposit, purchase and amount views. even if i add only one view in tableRow, it gives the same error.